# Entity Framework - Get Followers Posts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4, ef-fluent-api

I have written a REST API using Entity Framework with Fluent API. In that I want to get the posts created by my followers. I have retrieved the list of followers but want their posts too.

I have User entity and Posts entity as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class BlogPost
{
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And the followers/following relationships between users as follows:

```
public class UserRelationship
{
    public User UserId { get; set; }

    public User Follower { get; set; }
}
```

Now how can I retrieve the posts of my followers? Or do I have to change the structure itself?

Answer (score 0):

Retaining your current model structure, you will need to do a get on BlogPost entity for the follower. This will give you the posts from followers. However, this will add additional trip to database and also some translation on the server side code.

In my opinion, the model should be a bit different. User is the parent entity and it should have details of blog posts too. Thinking in terms of document based NoSQL database, User is easily identifiable as an aggregate so it must be the able to facilitate any traversal your application might need.

So, in the code, I would prefer something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ICollection<BlogPost> Blogs
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ICollection<User> Followers
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public User CreatedBy
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

On the database side, you will need to employ mapping tables approach to set up many to many relationship between users.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Using this I can able to get posts of individual user but I want to get posts of all followers like in twitter. Would this model suitable for that also?

Comment: @itdeeps I don't know how twitter works but you can get all the posts for all the followers if you populate the Followers property. You will be loading user and blog details for followers which IMHO would make your app less chatty. I believe in sending optimally more data to client than going to server all the time.However, you will need to evaluate yourself what the optimal message size and details are for you.